# Is there any way to svn cp and carry depth information with it?

Tags: svn

We have a very large repository, and my project only uses a subset of it. So, I've painstakingly set depth on a bunch of directories under trunk/ so that I normally only check out a subset of it.

But when I branch, svn wants to check out all of the new branch. Is there any way to also copy over all the depth settings to the new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depth is part of your working copy only, it is not a part of the repository. If you use the same working copy, then after creating the branch you should be able to `svn switch` to it, retaining all the depth settings.